# Tooltip for badges on the profile top section

Tags: feature-request, badges, profile-page, tooltips

I just noticed that there is no tooltip for badges on the profile top section:

> [image: top section]

In badge section tooltips are visible:

> [image: badges]

I see no reason to not display tooltips for badges on the top section of the user profile. Could it please be added? At least for consistency in profile page.

Comment: In the profile page, it requires a click to show the tooltip, i.e. it's there, just not really as a popup.

Comment: @ShadowWizard true, but ordinary tooltip can also be added.

Comment: Yeah, but then it will appear weird that the same text appears both on hover and when clicking, so I'm not sure about this. Maybe add "click for more details" tooltip? That would make more sense.

Comment: @ShadowWizard or just add `...` after regular tooltip text as for some menu items in Windows.